# Unirest get large file fails due to out of memory exception

Tags: java, rest, unirest

I'm using unirest to perform a get operation from a server. My problem is that when a large file is downloaded the action fails with a out of memory exception.

```
HttpResponse<InputStream> responseGet = Unirest.get("http://localhost:8080/BigDataTEst")
        .header("content-type", "*/*")
        .asBinary();
```

Is there a way to solve this issue using unirest?

Comment: For future reference; this bug is fixed only in the Unirest v4.0 version which does not use the Apache HTTP client. See https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java/issues/180 and https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java/issues/372

Answer (score 0):

On which JRE version you run the application?

I had the same issue (heap space / out of memory error) for large files (above 100 mb) when I was using Unirest. The problem was laying on Apache Http Components library (it was exactly Arrays.copyOf method which was used under the hood by Apache Http Components).

When I started testing it on JRE 8 x64 the problem disappear (I suspect that implementation copyOf has been changed or something like that).

So I suggest to try on different JRE or you could always use Apache Commons IO and `FileUtils.copyURLToFile`